# Does an Oracle incremental level 1 backup need archive logs to identify the differences since the last incremental level 0 (full) backup?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

Let's say we do a full incremental level 0 backup (full database backup) and then, for some reason, we need to delete some archive logs (generated after the full database backup) and then run an incremental level 1 backup (incremental backup). Will this incremental backup be okay without the deleted archive logs? Or does it need those archives to know the differences since the level 0 (full) backup? (I know we must have the archives logs **after** incremental level 1 to do a full recovery).

If no, how Oracle track those differences since incremental level 0 (without block change tracking)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCN is written to every block so RMAN get SCN of full backup and backup only blocks with SCN later than the full one.
No archive logs are required

Comment: Thanks. Also, I just found the confirmation in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/rman-backup-concepts.html#GUID-D3BD53B8-91F3-474C-BD10-00AE9B30E610